# Error returning an array of doubles

Tags: c++, arrays, return, return-type

```
double add_physics_vector(vector<double> v1, vector<double> v2)
{
    double horizontal_1 = v1[1] * cos(v1[0]);
    double vertical_1 = v1[1] * sin(v1[0]);
    double horizontal_2 = v2[1] * cos(v2[0]);
    double vertical_2 = v2[1] * sin(v2[0]);

    double horizontal_total = horizontal_1 + horizontal_2;
    double vertical_total = vertical_1 + vertical_2;
    double final_magnitude = sqrt(pow(horizontal_total, 2) + pow(vertical_total, 2));
    double final_direction = atan2(vertical_total, horizontal_total);
    double final_set[2] = {final_direction, final_magnitude};
    return final_set;
}
```

When I try to return `final_set` in my `main()` function, the compiler (g++-4.7) gives me this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ in return
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: You can't return an array. Use a vector, or `std::array`.

Comment: @BrianBi had no idea! Isn't a vector a kind of array though? Do you know what specifically about the structure of the two makes them different for return statements?

Comment: No, a vector is something that is sort of like an array, but not really. It's actually a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an array (which is decaying into a pointer), but you said you'd return a `double`. Use a vector instead:

```
vector<double> final_set = {final_direction, final_magnitude};
return final_set;
```

Your function will then be declared as:

```
vector<double> add_physics_vector(vector<double> v1, vector<double> v2);
```

If you want to avoid dynamic memory allocation, simply return a `pair<double, double>`:

```
pair<double, double> add_physics_vector(vector<double> v1, vector<double> v2)
{
    // ...as before
    return make_pair(final_direction, final_magitude);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the return type of that function be a double, not `double *` so of course that is why you are getting the error message.

I suggest using `malloc` to create a new array of doubles and then returning it:

```
double * make_array()
{
    double * array = malloc(sizeof(double) * 2);
    if (array == NULL) { /* .. error handling */ }
    return array;
}
```

Alternatively, since you are just returning two doubles, you could make a class or struct to hold the doubles, and return those directly.  Then you don't have to deal with `malloc` and `free`.  The advantage of this is that it makes your code clearer because it forces you to give names to these two doubles.

```
struct Vector
{
    double direction;
    double magnitude;
}

Vector make_vector()
{
    vector = (Vector){ 1, 2 };
    return vector;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::array` from the C++ standard library.